# Selection out of range in Telerik RadComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have `Telerik RadComboBox` ,

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="comboTown" Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

And I bind this table

```
Town
-----
TownOne
TownTwo
TownThree
TownFour
```

to `comboTown` show as below

```
  comboTown.DataSource = DB.Towns.ToList();
  comboTown.DataTextField = "Town";
  comboTown.DataValueField = "Town";
```

But , when I set `selectedValue` for `comboTown` likes `comboTown.SelectedValue= "TownTwo";`

I get this error message
`Selection out of range

Parameter name: value`

I want to know why , what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
comboTown.SelectedValue= "TownTwo"
```

add code

> comboTown.DataBind()

Comment: Can you post your code here, or you can try using: SelectedIndex instead of SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked for me :

Mark Up:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="comboTown" Width="150px" />
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnSetSelectedValue" 
 OnClick="btnSetSelectedValue_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
```

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       comboTown.DataSource = new List<string> { "TownOne", 
                                                 "TownTwo", 
                                                 "TownThree", 
                                                 "TownFour" 
                                               };
            comboTown.DataBind();
    }
 }

 protected void btnSetSelectedValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        comboTown.SelectedValue = "TownThree";
 }
```

As you can see - I have a combo box. On page load if it is not a postback I bind it to values. I have a button and on click of button I do a postback and set a selected value on combo box to "TownThree". This worked for me.